# TensorFlow tf.train.Saver() not working on tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I wrote this generalised TensorFlow code and want to `save` and `restore` models. But apparently the error is that there is no variables to save. I did everything as given in this official [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model). **Ignore** the `__init__` method except the last line, since it only takes relevant parameters to train the model with, also there is no Syntax Errors. The error it produces is given below the code.

```html
class Neural_Network(object):
    
    def __init__(self, numberOfLayers, nodes, activations, learningRate,  
                 optimiser = 'GradientDescent', regularizer = None, 
                 dropout = 0.5, initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()):
        self.numberOfLayers = numberOfLayers
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.activations = activations
        self.learningRate = learningRate
        self.regularizer = regularizer
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.initializer = initializer
        if(optimiser == 'GradientDescent'):
            self.optimiser = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learningRate)
        elif(optimiser == 'AdamOptimiser'):
            self.optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learningRate)
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        
        
    def create_Neural_Net(self, numberOfFeatures):
        self.numberOfFeatures = numberOfFeatures
        self.X = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = (None, self.numberOfFeatures), name = 'Input_Dataset')
        #self.output = None
        
        for i in range(0, self.numberOfLayers):
            if(i == 0):
                layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(self.X, self.nodes[i], 
                                                          activation_fn = self.activations[i],
                                                          weights_initializer = self.initializer, 
                                                          biases_initializer = self.initializer)                
            elif(i == self.numberOfLayers-1):
                self.output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(layer, self.nodes[i], 
                                                                activation_fn = self.activations[i],
                                                                weights_initializer = self.initializer, 
                                                                biases_initializer = self.initializer)
            else:
                layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(layer, self.nodes[i], 
                                                          activation_fn = self.activations[i],
                                                          weights_initializer = self.initializer, 
                                                          biases_initializer = self.initializer)
                
    
    def train_Neural_Net(self, dataset, labels, epochs):
        entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = self.output, labels = labels, name = 'cross_entropy')
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name = 'loss')
        hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(self.output)
        correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32)) 
        train_op = self.optimiser.minimize(loss)
        
        self.loss=[]
        self.accuracy = []
        
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            for i in range(0, epochs):
                _, l, acc = sess.run([train_op, loss, accuracy], feed_dict = {self.X:dataset}) 
                print('Loss in epoch ' + str(i) + ' is: ' + str(l))
                self.loss.append(l)
                self.accuracy.append(acc)
            self.saver.save(sess, './try.ckpt')
                
        return self.loss, self.accuracy
```

And ran this code as:

```html
nn = Neural_Network(2, [20,3], [tf.nn.relu, tf.nn.relu], 0.001, optimiser = 'AdamOptimiser')
nn.create_Neural_Net(4)
nn.train_Neural_Net(dataset, labels, 1000)
```

The error it gives is:

> ValueError: No variables to save

So what is wrong in this code? And how can I fix it?